# How to automatically mount a folder and change ownership from root in virtualbox

Tags: mount, permissions, virtualbox, fstab

It is my first time using virtualbox and ubuntu (14.04), I am on a host Windows 7 OS.

I am trying to mount a shared folder that has files I need to access both in the virtualbox and on the windows OS. I have successfully mounted them using the `vboxsf` from the `Guest Additions` installed.

To mount I used the command `sudo mount -t vboxsf <dir name in vbox> <directory in linux` for example I used `sudo mount -t vboxsf Test /home/user/Test`

I found several ways of mounting the directories automatically upon startup using for example the `/etc/rc.local` method ([here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868#p66406)) where you modify said file appending the command to it (without `sudo`). Or by using the `fstab` method ([here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4646#p16972)). I prefer the `rc.local` method personally.

Once mounted it has permissions `dr-xr-xr-x` however once mounted the directory is of `root` ownership and `chown user /home/user/Test` has no effect. This means I cannot make or change files in it as a normal user.

In the VirtualBox the directory to be shared is not set as read-only.

Is there a way to automatically mount the shared folder and assign ownership to my non `root` user?

Comment: Excellent thread I found on the forum https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=79965 . I recommend anyone reading this post to read it.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you have the guest additions installed, use the VirtualBox menu:

> Devices > Shared Folders...

Add the path, name and enable "Auto-mount" and "Make permanent" options.

Finally add your user to the group with:

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a myusername
```

Logout and back again or reboot the machine to complete the process (thanks @Fo).

Groups are stored in `/etc/group`, according to the [usermod man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod).

Comment: I tried this and was unable to access the shared folders even after confirming I had been added to the group.

Comment: @Jake Are your guest additions correctly installed?

Comment: need to log out and back after adding yourself to the group

Comment: I'm having issues on this too, it urks me to see `root vboxsf` in the symlinked files I created in my home dir for the mounted share, but the main problem is i get read problems too.   Isn't it plausible that webfiles in my case that are set up for permissions such as `755` will now need `775`, etc..?  This is a no-go, and I need a solution to mount it to my user if so.  The `uid` and `gid` in `fstab` wasnt working for me, maybe since its auto mounted by guest additions i gather, im really not sure why `fstab` wasn't working.  When moving files i see this `mv: cannot create symbolic link`

Comment: @BrianThomas Your issues with symlinks seem different from the original question. You might want to consider creating a new question for them.

Comment: What are the security implications of doing that? I can imagine changing the mount gives less of an attack vector.

Answer (score 24):

Ah the curse of writing a question and then finding the answer immediately after.

I didn't use the full command suggested in [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders)

`sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$GID share ~/host`

So to add ownership and automatically mount in virtualbox via `vboxsf` in Ubuntu add to the `/etc/rc.local` file before the `exit 0` line the command as follows:

`mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 <folder name given in VirtualBox> /home/<user>/where/ever/you/want`

Comment: I might add that shared folders that are shared from NTFS might have some specific corner-case problems.  You could work around it with losetup and chain mounting a file as a filesystem.

Comment: Furthermore, commands to change ownership on the vboxsf-munted partition will not take effect. See http://superuser.com/questions/640027/why-cant-i-chown-a-virtualbox-shared-folder

Comment: This solution "fixes" the mounting to a particular user id. Not sure if this is what the OP wanted. If different users are using this system, it will not work for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to first configure the shared drives in `Auto-mount` mode like in the first part of @Katu's answer. This will allow to get the mount configurations of the shared drives by running `mount`. You'll get something like:

```
$ mount
...
vbox-shared-dir on /media/sf_vbox-shared-dir type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=998,dmode=0770,fmode=0770,tag=VBoxAutomounter)...
```

One can then use this information to update `/etc/fstab/` with an additional line, replacing `UID` and `GID` accordingly and removing the tag option:

```
vbox-shared-dir   /media/sf_vbox-shared-dir  vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=<UID>,gid=<GID>,dmode=0770,fmode=0770 0       0
```

After this you should be able to mount the volume automatically running the command:

```
# mount vbox-shared-dir
```

Then you just need to remove the  `Auto-mount` option in the virtual box configuration because the volume gets mounted automatically during boot.