# Changing ownership does not persist in Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine

Tags: mount, virtualization

I have mounted a new disk to a virtual machine in a specific directory (NewDrive) and changed ownership using `sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop NewDrive/`, and then edited the `fstab` file by adding

```
/dev/sdb1 /home/hduser/NewDrive ext4 defaults 0 0
```

I have no copy paste issue before restarting VM but every time I restart the VM I am losing permission. How can I make the permission settings persistent?

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/481559/how-to-automatically-mount-a-folder-and-change-ownership-from-root-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
/dev/sdb1 /home/hduser/NewDrive ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,uid=1001  0 0
```

With the Uid set to your uid. I had to do that on a non-virtual machine

Comment: Losing mount point after giving restart.

Comment: the directory I am pointing to the disk