# All of a sudden I'm getting permission errors

Tags: permissions, filesystem, ext4, groups

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and facing a problem. 
All of a sudden I'm unable to edit files that I could before, I cannot run programs due to permission errors.

I'm always logged in as a user `ejaz` belonging to primary group `ejaz` and secondary groups `root` `adm` `cdrom` `sudo` `dip` `www-data` `plugdev` `lpadmin` `sambashare` `kismet` `wireshark` `docker`. I have several websites in sub-directories of `/var/www/html/` (not in `~/public_html` because it is a dev machine with no security/sharing considerations). Taking a website, `/var/www/html/test`, for example; it belongs to user:group `www-data:www-data`. Me, logged in as `ejaz`, am getting permission errors while editing files in `test` directory. I seem to have correct group permissions to edit this directory.

## Output of `groups` command

```
~ » groups ejaz                                                                                                                                                              
ejaz : ejaz root adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare kismet wireshark docker
```

## Permissons for `test` site

```
/var/www/html » l | grep test
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  9  2017 test
```

## But any editing results in permission errors

```
/var/www/html » cd test 

/var/www/html/test » l                                                                                                                                                           
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Apr  9  2017 .
drwxrwxr-x 87 www-data www-data 4.0K Jul 10 06:50 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Apr  9  2017 blah.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   16 Apr  9  2017 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   73 Apr  9  2017 index1.html

/var/www/html/test » touch blah.html
touch: cannot touch 'blah.html': Permission denied
```

## Output of `id` command

```
/var/www/html/test » id -Gn
ejaz
```

which is understandable since `ejaz` is the primary group.

**But** If I `su` as `ejaz`, I'm able to edit the file in terminal and in any program that is launched from *that particular terminal instance*

## Question

Why am I not able to edit the files all of a sudden and how was I able to edit those files before? All I did since yesterday was to run Ubuntu's apt upgrade.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for reading.

## Update # 1

## Output of `sudo mount` command

```
~ » sudo mount                                                                    
[sudo] password for ejaz: 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4021496k,nr_inodes=1005374,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=808412k,mode=755)
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4917.snap on /snap/core/4917 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4650.snap on /snap/core/4650 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4830.snap on /snap/core/4830 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_62.snap on /snap/pycharm-community/62 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_60.snap on /snap/pycharm-community/60 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_64.snap on /snap/pycharm-community/64 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/dev/sda4 on /mnt/SSD2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=808412k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

## Output of `sudo df -h` command

```
~ » sudo df -h                                                                  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           790M  9.3M  781M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        82G   75G  2.3G  98% /
tmpfs           3.9G  165M  3.7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop1       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop2       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/loop4      233M  233M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/62
/dev/loop3      240M  240M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/60
/dev/loop5      237M  237M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-community/64
/dev/sda4       136G  125G   11G  92% /mnt/SSD2
tmpfs           790M   28K  790M   1% /run/user/1000
```

## Update # 2

[image]

## Update # 3

reducing reserved blocks to 0 didn't help

[image]

## Update # 4

I forgot to mention it earlier but I think it is worth mentioning that I often run Windows 7 on this PC using VirtualBox. Windows has access to `/var/www/html/` and `/mnt/SSD2/` via VirtualBox sharing. I have been running Windows for ~ a year but could that have caused the permissions mess?
Regarding the extent of what Windows does to the shared directories, I exclusively use Widows to run Adobe Photoshop, so Windows essentially reads some images from `/mnt/SSD2` or `/var/www/html/html` and stores images in `/mnt/SSD2/*`. **No** huge file manipulation is done in Windows on shared directories, e.g., compressing directories, extracting compressed files, moving directories around, setting permissions etc.

## Update # 5

[image]

The blurred out text is of following pattern..

```
/var/www/html/magento_site_1
/var/www/html/magento_site_1/var/session/sess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/var/www/html/magento_site_1
/var/www/html/magento_site_1/var/session/sess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/var/www/html/magento_site_1
/var/www/html/magento_site_1/var/session/sess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
/var/www/html/magento_site_1
/var/www/html/magento_site_1/var/session/sess_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
....
```

with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` being a random string. The screenshot is complete output.

## Update #6

Output of

```
cd /var/www/html/test 
sudo trace-cmd record -o /tmp/trace.dat -e all touch blah.html
cd /tmp 
run trace-cmd report
```

[image: x]

## Update 7

I left my computer turned on overnight to download some files in `/mnt/SSD2` on the single SSD my computer has, and came back to this in the morning

[image]

Upon rebooting I got a `busybox` `initramfs` command prompt where running `fsck /dev/sda1/` allowed me to use my PC again, but is this connected to permissions issues I'm having? Is my SSD dying? Is it the newly installed kernel which was installed using `sudo apt upgrade` shortly before the permissions issue started occurring?

Comment: Just added listing of `test` directory

Comment: First check: Is the partition with this file system mounted writeable? Does it have enough space?

Comment: `/` has ~8GB of free space. About file system being writable, how do I check that? I *am* able to edit files in the terminal instance if I run `su ejaz` command it in.

Comment: What kind of packages where upgraded ? Maybe a reboot is necessary ?

Comment: Maybe you only have <5% of space left on the device ? which would explain why you cannot write as user but as root (via su) ? Could you please add the output of `sudo df -h` and `sudo mount` to the post, so we can see what's what?

Comment: @RobertRiedl I have added the output of commands. Regarding space issue, I believe if have run this particular PC disk 99% occupied in the past.

Comment: but i do not have anything against freeing up space if that fixes the issue :D It would only warrant some explanation for my better understanding :)

Comment: its a 'safety feature' as you might be able to tell. if you have one partiton for everything (like it seems you do) one user home can easly block the whole OS, if there is no space left to write. so as a standard option, we reserve 5% of space for root (all cirtical apps run as GID 0 / root) so that you can at least login, or update packages, etc...

Comment: cleaning up will probably help you right now, but in the long run, you might want to make a separate partition for your data, like `/var/www` or even `/home/`

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo lsof +D /var/www/html/` to your question?

Comment: And a another question, is the `test` folder generated?

Comment: I'm not sure what "is the test folder generated" means

Comment: @SimonSudler please see update # 5

Comment: what is the output `lsattr` ?

Comment: `-------------e-- ./test`

Comment: @Ejaz I meant is the folder created/removed by some script?

Comment: Can you please run `sudo inotifywait -r -m /var/www/html/test` on the folder and try the creation of the file `blah.html`

Comment: @SimonSudler No the directory was created via command line.

Comment: Come on guys, I'm tired of doing `su ejaz` all the time :(

Comment: did you look into my comment about the virtualbox permissions ? i.e. `sudo usermod -aG vboxsf ejaz` ?

Comment: please at the output of `inotifywait` it will help identify the problem

Comment: Please also take a look at the out put of `dmesg`. Are there any errors from the filesystem?

Comment: @SimonSudler what command do you want me to run? Only `dmesg` ?

Comment: Yes, `dmesg`. Just check that there are now errors from the filesystem

Comment: Nothing looks error like to me in `dmesg` output. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, but you are not going to like it: `cd /var/www/html/test` and run `sudo trace-cmd record -o /tmp/trace.dat -e all touch blah.html`. Then goto `cd /tmp` and run `trace-cmd report`. This will show you all kernel activities resulting from the `touch` command. And somewhere in this output is the reason for the permission deny problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help Simon. The output starts with `version = 6
trace-cmd: No such file or directory
[xen:xen_mmu_set_pud] function sizeof not defined
[xen:xen_mmu_set_pte_atomic] function sizeof not defined`. Screenshot of the first page added to question.

Comment: @SimonSudler please see the update. I can't believe I bought the computer in 2010 :D

Comment: There is something realy wrong with that system... the errors at the beginnig of the trace report should not be there. I problem with the permission should be inside the log-output after that

Comment: Honestly I don't know whats wrong with your machine. I checked, and it seems the trace errors you see are related to the old trace that 16.04 LTS uses. But I think its time for you to check if you have a full backup of all your data from this host.

Answer (score 5):

*Preface: I don't know anything about snaps.*

**A standard option for ext filesystems is to reserve 5% of space for root on `/`**

So it looks like, to me, that `/var/www/html/` is part of the root partition, which has only 2% space left, looking at the ouput of `df`. 
As a standard option, Linux will retain 5% of your partition space of `/`for root. So that would explain why you cannot edit with your user account, but with `su`.

To check if this is really the case, you can use `tune2fs` to see how many reserved block you have

`sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`

look if `Reserved block count:` is higher than 0.

`Reserved block count:     3034088`

You might want modify this, as a short time solution, for example, to 1%

`sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1`

or with `-r` for the number of `blocks` (can also be set to 0)

**But it would be a good idea to leave the 5% for root and move your data files to a separate partition.**

**[Here is a good explantation why this is a good idea.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7965/271588)**

---

Other ways to quickly gain some filespace on `/`, if you don't have separate partitions for `/var`, `/home`, etc:

- clean up your user homes
- remove old log files
- remove old packages / kernels with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What am I looking for in output of `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` command? It says `... Inode count: 5431296 - Block count: 21693847 - Reserved block count: 1084692 - Free blocks: 1782825 - Free inodes: 3609939 ...`

Comment: look for `reserved blocks` as mentioned above. if you have them, then it is as I expected and a clean up will help, as well as reducing the % of reserved blocks

Comment: I was able to free up 5.6GB in `/dev/sda1` but unfortunately it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Please see the screenshot I've added to the question. It shows 4 vertically stacked terminal windows.

Comment: Did you try `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1` to temp. disable block reserving ?

Comment: No, I did not do that. Can you please explain how this block reserving thing kicked in? I mean I have been able to use this PC with same  software/hardware configuration for ~2 years with having way lower free space that it has right now.

Comment: If you had lower space than this, then the block reserve is not the issue - sorry. This is normally set at setup time, but can be changed any time. To make sure this is not the issue, I'd try to set it to 0. It doesn't hurt, doesn't require to reboot or anything.

Comment: Were you able to try `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sda1` or `sudo tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sda1` ?

Comment: Yes I did and unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. How do I revert it to default?

Comment: Please see Update # 4, I strongly suspect that might be causing the problems.

Comment: You can use `sudo tune2fs -m 5 /dev/sda1` to get the default value of 5% back. Regarding the virtualbox suspicion: You can try to add your user to the virtualbox group, like `sudo usermod -aG vboxsf ejaz `  then login/logout.

Answer (score 0):

This will not apply 100% to you, but it is related, and hopefully will point you in the right direction. I suspect, as you say you do, that the problem is about the shared Virtualbox folders. Basically, folders accessed from 2 different OSes, each with their own filesystems/permissions, and since you can't enforce either one 100% or you lose all access from the other...

Yeah Virtualbox is likely trying to walk that tightrope between the two, without falling off on either side.

Anyway the references I found are to the opposite of your setup, Windows host and Ubuntu guest. But the same kinds of permissions shenanigans.

[Windows host, Ubuntu guest, permission problems, with solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036375/196774)